# Wordpress admin - You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I got this error(You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page) when try to login, i have changed access details in phpmyadmin but it didn't work. So, I have seen in some post about forced-upload.php. It worked, now i can enter in to Dashboard. But there are no tabs (pages, posts, appearence, tabs). So, i tried to enter to directly type the url to edit css like http://example.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php. But i am getting this error "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." again. So, i can enter in to dashboard, but not into theme-editors, or pages?

I changed wp-debug - true in wp-config.php and got these warnings

Warning: include(/home2/abramson/public_html/wp-content/advanced-cache.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/abramson/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 65

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home2/abramson/public_html/wp-content/advanced-cache.php' 
for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php') in /home2/abramson/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 65

Need help

Thanks

Comment: and you are supposed to have those privileges or what? And it still won't work?

Comment: yes it still not works, i can enter only dashboard. In that, i can only see profile and dashboard tabs. Nothing there, if i try direct url of plugins.php, above mentioned error comes? Need help

Comment: and how can you be sure you didn't have your privileges reduced? are you the only one working on the page?

Comment: yes, i am only one working on this

Comment: It sounds to me like you're logging in to WordPress's dashboard with a user without administrative privilege. The error message you mentioned is the one WordPress generates in that situation.  If you control this web site, you should use the administrative login.